# FancyBox/ Popup Deeplinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, deep-linking

How do you implement deep linking on a page so when the user comes that that page from an external link, that fancybox modal is initiated. I'm new to JS/Jquery

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing this morning and found your question as well as a forum post that has an answer.

```
(function()
{
  var qs = location.search.slice( 1 ), 
      params = qs.match( /&?ab=(\d+)\|(\d+)/ );

  if( params )
    page( Number( params[ 1 ] ), Number( params[ 2 ] ) );

})();
```

"Then if you link to that page passing your two numeric parameters in this form:

concert.html?ab=1|5

It should have the stunning effect of calling page(1, 5); when the page loads. "

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=247899

Hope it helps - it helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it for myself with fancybox2 and url hashes.

You can use Fancybox callbacks to set and unset hashes.
I used data attributes in the img tag to store img identifiers.
Then you can check for a hash in the url at pageload, get the index and open the fancybox with the given index.

```
  var option = {
        afterLoad: function(links) {
            var title = links.element.attr('data-my-img');
            location.hash = title;
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            location.hash = '';
        }
    },
    hash = location.hash.substr(1),
    gallery = $('.fancybox');
    if(hash.length > 0){
        //id
        var i = null;
        gallery.each(function(index) {
            var o = $(this).attr('data-my-img');
            if($(this).attr('data-my-img') == hash){
                i = index;
                return;
            }
        });
        if(i != null){
            option.index = i;
            $.fancybox.open(gallery, option);
        }
    }
    gallery.fancybox(option);
```

Comment: Just refer to this link http://jsfiddle.net/f2fRM/2/show. remove "show" from url to see the code